# Should I upgrade to 20.x under these circumstances?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I currently am running my own Ubuntu server

> No LSB modules are available. 
> Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
> Description:   Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 
> Release:   18.04 
> Codename:  bionic

Now I made this myself, and I barely know linux, so it took me a lot to get this done.

Am using this server to run some Perl testing.

The logon now recommends this:

> New release '20.04.1 LTS' available.
> Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Since I'm so unqualified, and don't recall everything I installed...maybe it's wise that I skip it? Might not be worth the trouble?

Not even sure of everything I installed, i.e. ban2fail, etc.

If I had a additional laptop, this wouldn't be a question.

Advice sorely needed.

Comment: Advice: Start keeping track of what you install, when, why, how, and a link to whatever instructions you used. Write it down. You WON'T recall the important details when you need them. My own journal-of-install-notes is merely a 100-line-or-so text file for each of my systems...but it means I can rebuild any of my systems from bare-metal to an *exact duplicate* in about 90 minutes, including full data restore. The text files are backed up to my phone, so I always have my notes handy when things go terribly wrong (which is when I need them).

Comment: More Advice: If you cannot throw away your system and restore from a backup, then you are in fetters; your strategy is hope-for-the-best. This site is littered with the tears of folks who lost their data hoping for the best. Your system WILL fail someday. Don't worry about release-upgrading. Instead, worry about preserving (backing up) your data. After that, worry about how to rebuild your system from scratch. Then, when you are in control of the situation, it will be safe to upgrade.

Comment: To add to @user535733's sage advice above - an untested backup is not a backup at all. You need to verify the integrity and function of your backup solution.

Comment: I admit it, I did a sloppy job of setting it up. I just hand no idea what I was getting into, and just needed a web and MySQL server.  But then you add those little things, ban2fail, etc.etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have till April 2023 before 18.04 is End Of Life so if it works maybe do not fix it?

Comment: That is true, but don't forget many packages in *bionic* (18.04) are no longer supported, as the April-2023 applies to any packages in the 'main' repository, but not 'universe' which included a number of packages with 9 months of support (not all 18.04 *flavors* were LTS for example), with most having 3 years of support which is the *norm* for 'universe' or community packages. Yes many Ubuntu Server users are reluctant to add 'universe' to avoid this issue, but the OP may have added sources that don't come with 5 years of support...  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Noted and thanks for the info @guiverc